# Mongoose .find() = Query, but when does the Query finalize?

Tags: node.js, json, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

This is just a general question but I can provide an example if necessary. I've been working on a MongoDB/Mongoose, Node.JS, Express, and Handlebars stack app recently and I've ran into some issues with what is being passed from my route to the client side when dealing with Mongoose .find() queries.

I prefer to async await my queries. I have a deeply nested populate query that brings in all the data I need into one object. This is a very simplified breakdown of what I do

```
async function() { const finalObject = await Model.find({}).populate([*alot more populates*]) }
```

I pass this into my res.render() route, as so:

```
res.render('index', { finalObject });
```

The majority of my experience has been pretty straight forward. I have one issue in a separate stack overflow question about populating the same model twice in one chain (at different levels). I won't address that here.

I decided to do some calculations before passing the object to the route and attach some new values to the properties of the documents. This is where things get weird. I do some calculations and add new properties to documents (these properties are not part of the Schema). When the object is passed to the client-side, those properties I added are available to use (no problem here).

I needed to decode the finalObject into JSON and pass it as JSON as well for an easy use of the data in my client side JavaScript `encodedFinalObject = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(finalObject));`

I decode it on the client side: `clientSideFinalObject = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(encodedFinalObject));` and the properties I added are not there!

I'm wondering, how could the new properties I added pass through when I send the object but not pass through when I send the JSON? The decoding is the last thing I do before rendering the page, so it's not a matter of not having my code in the wrong order. I add the properties to the object then decode it.

Some research led me to find out that Model.find({}) does not return a native JavaScript object, but instead a Query. I'm assuming this is a user-defined class data-type that has special behaviors. My assumption is that between the passing from the back-end to the front-end, there is some middle step where the Query does its final processing.

The opposite situation has also occurred. As a solution to this, I decoded the Query finalObject immediately after the Model.find({}) and re-encoded it into a native JavaScript object. After that, I did all my calculations, attached the results as properties to the documents, and sent that new version over as the main finalObject (I still also sent over a separate decoded object for client-side JavaScript use).

This solved the issue of the new properties not being there. They appeared, but this time the decoded then re-encoded finalObject did not have the virtual properties of my Models. The main model has a virtual property that calculates some of it's other properties. It's almost as if that part of the query didn't execute within the .find({}) process. So, when I decoded the finalObject, the virtual properties were never there and were never decoded.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on? Thank you!